# ¿Cómo le añado una línea de tendencia a mi gráfico de dispersión?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
gplot(Datos) + 
   geom_point(aes(x=s,y=Gdp)) + 
   geom_text(aes(x=s,y=Gdp,label=País),size=3) + 
   ylab("Tasa de crecimiento del PIB")+ xlab("tasa de ahorro")
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla es usar un [`geom_smooth()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html):

```
geom_smooth(aes(x=s,y=Gdp),
            method = "lm",
            se = FALSE)
```

Con `method = "lm"` establecemos que se aplique el modelo líneal.  Puedes simplificar el gráfico si haces un mapeo global:

```
ggplot(Datos, aes(x=s,y=Gdp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=País),size=3) + 
  ylab("Tasa de crecimiento del PIB")+ xlab("tasa de ahorro") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```